# Calcular altura arbol orientado C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase tree para representar arboles orientados (No binarios). 
Los nodos son representados por una celda, que tiene el metodo lchild() que nos da el hijo mas izquierdo y right() o siplemente incrementando (como en list) para obtener su hermano que le sigue.
Acá dejo codigo para listar orden previo, para tener en cuenta.

```
void oprev(tree<int> &T, tree<int>::iterator p){
tree<int>::iterator q;
if (p == T.end()){ 
    return;
}
cout<<*p<<" ";
q = p.lchild();
while( q != T.end() ){
    oprev (T, q++);
}

void oprev(tree<int> &T){
oprev(T,T.begin());}
```

Necesito calucar la altura de un arbol. Tengo este codigo pero no es correcto

```
int altura(tree<int> &T,tree<int>::iterator p, int &x){
tree<int>::iterator q;
if (p == T.end()){ 
    return x;
}
q = p.lchild();
while( q != T.end() ){
    altura(T, q++,x);
}
if(p.lchild()!=T.end()){
    x++;
}
return x;}
```

Teniendo este arbol.

[image: AOO]

Como altura obtengo 5.

Reconozco que el error está en que el contador, a veces suma de vuelta cuando pasa por niveles que anteriormente ya ha pasado. No se como puedo evitar esto. 
Desde ya gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Si por "altura del árbol" te refieres a cuán largas son sus "ramas" no lo estás haciendo bien. Tienes varios problemas de concepto.

#### Propuesta.

Añade a tu clase plantilla `tree` una función `altura` que consultará a todos los nodos de su raíz cuán profundos son y se quedará con el máximo de ellos:

```
int tree::altura()
{
    int a = 0;

    for (auto &nodo : raiz)
        a = std::max(a, deep(nodo, 0))

    return a;
}
```

El código anterior asume que tu clase `tree` tiene un nodo llamado `raiz` y que dicho nodo provee las funciones `begin` y `end`.

La función anterior llama a la función recursiva `deep` que hace casi lo mismo que la función `altura` con la diferencia que a cada nivel de recursión incrementa el nivel en 1, para ello esta función debe recibir el nodo desde el que calcular y la profundidad desde la que empezar a contar:

```
int tree::deep(Nodo &n, int nivel)
{
    int a = nivel;

    for (auto &nodo : raiz_del_arbol)
        a = std::max(a, deep(nodo, nivel + 1))

    return a;
}
```

Si el nodo al que hemos llegado no tiene hijos, su nivel será el nivel proveído en la llamada.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Tienes unos fallos de diseño que me gustaría comentarte:

- No uses funciones libres para hacer estas operaciones, estas funciones te obligan a exponer los datos de tu clase rompiendo así la encapsulación.
- Si realmente debes usar funciones libres, usa una función plantilla, o te verás obligado a crear una versión por cada instanciación de la plantilla `tree`.

Answer (score 2):

Estás contando el número de hijos, no la altura.

La diferencia es que, para un nodo cualquiera, la altura será **el máximo** de las alturas de los dos hijos, no la suma de las alturas.

Así que tira hacia (pseudocódigo para no quitarte el placer de programar):

```
int altura(nodo n) {

   int alturaDerecha = 0; int alturaIzquierda = 0;

   si es n un nodo terminal {
      return 1;
   }

   si existeHijoDerecho de n {
      alturaDerecha = altura(n.hijoDerecho());
   }

   si existeHijoIzquierdo de n {
      alturaIzquierda = altura(n.hijoIzquierdo());
   }

   int alturaHijos = max(alturaDerecha, alturaIzquierda);
   return alturaHijos + 1;
}
```

Si lo encuentras más legible, puedes mover la comprobación del nodo terminal antes de buscar las alturas de los hijos.

Comment: El problema es que no es un arbol binario, en un mismo nivel puedo tener muchos nodos. Edite el posta para dejarlo mas claro. No se si me explico

Comment: El algoritmo seguiría siendo el mismo, básicamente. Sólo tienes que quedarte con la altura máxima de los N hijos que tenga el nodo actual.